# Do Arcane Strike and similar feats stack with Enhancement bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, bonus-type

[Arcane Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/arcane-strike-combat/):

> As a swift action, you can imbue your weapons with a fraction of your power. For 1 round, your weapons deal +1 damage and are treated as magic for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction. For every five caster levels you possess, this bonus increases by +1, to a maximum of +5 at 20th level.

By my reading, this is an untyped bonus. Am I wrong, or does it stack with weapon enhancements (and all other bonuses) to attack and defence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes, it does.

[Arcane Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/arcane-strike-combat/) bonus is *untyped*. As such, it will stack with other bonuses, as long as they are not from the same source (here, the feat) or sources that explicitly call out that won't stack with *Arcane Strike* (there is none that I know about).